# Maintain same node ID's when importing nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, features, importing-exporting

I am using [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) with [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module, and then importing content while installing my profile. All works fine, but I want the node ID's to be retained while importing. I want it to be in same order as the source site.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think more detail here would clarify the question and help generate better answers.

- Are you moving to a new server?
- Importing content to another site that already has other content?
- Why are you worried about preserving the NIDs? External dependencies?
- Is order the only concern, or the actual NIDs themselves?

A couple of thoughts here that may help:

1. A core-rsync/sql-sync or sql-dump using [drush](http://drush.ws/) and import would
   maintain node IDs and machine names for all items. This does not
   involve 'features' in any way, and is more of a core operation which
   would would clone your install, overwriting any differences on
   site #2. Beware.
2. If you're only doing this once (and
   are only concerned about the NIDs), an  `ALTER TABLE node
   AUTO_INCREMENT = XXX;` (where XXX=your first old NID) statement in mySQL
   on your target Database BEFORE you import your nodes might help. This would not
   work, however, if you're not exporting a non-sequential NID list of
   nodes (i.e. 64, 65, 68). It also would most likely fail/destroy your
   target site if it already has NIDs that are greater than
   the first NID of the source (or any matching NIDs).

Answer (score 1):

In short no (not easily/safely anyway).

If you're looking for specific content ID's, you may want to look into putting the [UUID](http://drupal.org/project/uuid) module on your source/destination site.  As far as I'm aware, this will allow you to keep a unique identifier on your nodes that match across sites, even though the node ID's will be different.

Comment: Forgot to mention, UUID will also require some further work on your part.  I've not used it extensively though so may not be able to help much with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with a little work.

First, disable auto increment on node.nid & node_revision.vid.  Details an exercise for the reader.

Second, create a custom module w/ one function in it, say mymodule_ns($node).

copy and paste the contents of node_save from api.drupal.org into your function.

then (this current as of drupal 7.28) change the line in the else for

```
if($node->is_new)
```

that says

```
drupal_write_record('node', $node, 'nid);
```

to

```
drupal_write_record('node', $node);
```

Then change the line in the else under the

```
if($!empty($node->revision))
```

that says

```
_node_save_revision($node, $user->uid, 'vid');
```

to

```
_node_save_revision($node, $user->uid);
```

Enable the module.

Finally, create your nodes programmatically as usual with these changes:

1. set $node->nid = $node->vid = whatever you want on your object.
2. set $node->log to something non empty, say "imported node" or whatever you want.
3. call mymodule_ns instead of node_save.

Don't forget to turn auto increment back on on node & node_revision tables, and set the auto increment value to something greater than the highest nid you imported.

Happy hunting.